# How to stub a method of an object with specified params?

Tags: node.js, sinon

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method");
```

[Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/) tutorial explains stub but it, how to modify the above line to invoke/stub 'method' with a specified 'param' else do not stub it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `stub.withArgs` to stub a method with the expected arguments.

```
const stub = sinon.stub(object, 'method');
stub.withArgs(42).returns(1);
stub.withArgs(1).throws('BOOM!');
```